# Find first matched item from array using find/reduce/filter in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

the "result" will give me the type "Event | undefined".
is there any way to make the "result" to "Event"?
or is there any way to perform the same behavior with reduce() or map()?

My goal is to get the first match category from the array.

```
data: Event[] = [
  {
    title: "demo 1",
    category: "a"
  },
  {
    title: "demo 2",
    category: "b"
  },
  {
    title: "demo 3",
    category: "a"
  },
]

const result = data.find(item => item.category === 'a')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the category string you are comparing against will always exist, you can use the not null assertion operator `!`:

```
// Note: the type hinting here is optional
const result: Event = data.find(item => item.category === 'a')!;
```

Accessing an array by index will never give you `Event | undefined` for `Event[]`. So, you can also do something like this (again, you'd be ignoring the case where index can be `-1`):

```
const index = data.findIndex(item => item.category === 'a');
// Note: the type hinting here is optional
const result: Event = data[index];
```